# How to change comma with dot in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm in a hurry because i don't know how to change the item[] value. This value is a number with comma and i need it with dot. Here the code:

```
function gasofa(){
  var url = "https://sedeaplicaciones.minetur.gob.es/ServiciosRESTCarburantes/PreciosCarburantes/EstacionesTerrestres/";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url);
  var respText = response.getContentText('utf8');
  var dataAll = JSON.parse(respText);
  var precioArray = [];
  dataAll.ListaEESSPrecio.forEach(function(item){

    precioArray.push([
      item["Longitud (WGS84)"],
    ]);
  });
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = ss.getRange('A01'+ ':A0' + precioArray.length);
  range.setValues(precioArray);
}
```

Comment: `"2,79".replace(',','.')`?

Answer (score 0):

YourStringVariable.replace(/,/g, ".")

Comment: Yes, i know this line of code but i can´t put it in this part of my code:  " item["Longitud (WGS84)"]"